# Including an html file into another html file using Handlebars.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

In PHP, it's easy to include a file in another one to avoid redundancy of the code using the `include` keyword. Is there a similar solution in Node.JS using Handlebars.JS?

Answer (score 11):

From your question it sounds like you are looking for handlebars [partials](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html).  For an example check out https://github.com/donpark/hbs/tree/master/examples/partial.

In short, you'd have something which looked like:

index.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
</head>

<body>
{{> header}}
</body>
</html>
```

where `{{> header}}` is referencing the `header.hbs` partial.

Comment: This works if, for example I have in `header.hbs`  `<a href="/myprofile">{{datauser.name}} </a>`?